# How to upload large image files in azure storage using mobile service javascript

Tags: azure, blobstorage

I am creating a mobile service custom api for uploading an image to azure blob storage using below code

`blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream('ContainerName','BlobName', fs.createReadStream(fileName), fileName.size, { contentTypeHeader:'image/png' },function(error)
{
  if(error)
  {
       request.respond(200,error);`enter code here
  `} 
});`

when i try to upload image file > 1 MB it gives **"Request body maximum size limit was exceeded."** , its working fine when image size is <1MB